# Autodesk forge viewer using a material with a image texture

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need help on using a material with a image texture
Using the 2.9 viewer files.
I see that it uses revision 71 of three.js

I have created a custom shape.  A square out of vertices

I would like to use a image texture material

```
var shininess = 50, specular = 0x333333, bumpScale = 1, shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
var imgTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg" );
            imgTexture.wrapS = imgTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            imgTexture.anisotropy = 16;
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: imgTexture, color: 0xffffff, shading: shading } );
viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial("FloorMaterial", material, true);
```

...

```
// Convert Array to Vector Array and World Space
var vectorWorldArray = convertFloatArrayToVectorWorldArray(viewer,
        matrixWorld, floatArray);
var shape = new THREE.Shape(vectorWorldArray);
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
 geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
 geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 2, 3, 0 ) );
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var scene = viewer.impl.scene;
// mesh.translateZ( 10 );
scene.add(mesh);
```

The texture just shows up as all black

Only thing that comes up in chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116 m)
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0B70AB98]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0

I know that the texture exists

Is there a easier/correcct way of adding the image texture material ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like lambert needs a light other then what comes with the viewer

I switched to using BasicMaterial now my texture shows up.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: imgTexture, color: 0xffffff, shading: shading } );
```